# I want to find the element Rig, on clicking "Rig" -> dropdown opens having only element "Search"

Tags: selenium, testing

How to find ul and li tags

I want to find the element Rig, on clicking "Rig" -> dropdown opens having only element "Search"

Home

Rig

Rig

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aldc5.png)

Comment: Provide more information as: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Provide error stack trace. 5. Provide relevant HTML DOM with in the Question (not as an Attachment).

Answer (score 0):

Th element `button` with text `Rig` can be found using the xPath: `"//div[@id='3_menubar']/ul/li/button[contains(text(), 'Rig')]"`

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.t-Header-nav > div > ul li:nth-child(2) button"));
```